# getent passwd dosen't show users of LDAP server

Tags: ldap, authentication, ubuntu-14.04

I have made the LDAP authentification configurations and I try to authenticate to the LDAP server on Ubuntu 14.04 TLS.
This is the file nsswitch.conf :

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

# pre_auth-client-config # passwd:         compat ldap
passwd: files ldap
# pre_auth-client-config # group:          compat ldap
group: files ldap
# pre_auth-client-config # shadow:         compat ldap
shadow: files ldap

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

# pre_auth-client-config # netgroup:       nis
netgroup: nis
```

The command `getent passwd` returns the content of the file `/etc/passwd` without returning the LDAP users.
Even that I get all my entries using `ldapsearch`.

The file `/etc/ldap.conf` :

```
###DEBCONF###
##
## Configuration of this file will be managed by debconf as long as the
## first line of the file says '###DEBCONF###'
##
## You should use dpkg-reconfigure to configure this file via debconf
##

#
# @(#)$Id: ldap.conf,v 1.38 2006/05/15 08:13:31 lukeh Exp $
#
# This is the configuration file for the LDAP nameservice
# switch library and the LDAP PAM module.
#
# PADL Software
# http://www.padl.com
#

# Your LDAP server. Must be resolvable without using LDAP.
# Multiple hosts may be specified, each separated by a 
# space. How long nss_ldap takes to failover depends on
# whether your LDAP client library supports configurable
# network or connect timeouts (see bind_timelimit).
#host 127.0.0.1

# The distinguished name of the search base.
base dc=souad,dc=com

# Another way to specify your LDAP server is to provide an
uri ldap://192.168.95.133:389/
# Unix Domain Sockets to connect to a local LDAP Server.
#uri ldap://127.0.0.1/
#uri ldaps://127.0.0.1/   
#uri ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fldapi_sock/
# Note: %2f encodes the '/' used as directory separator

# The LDAP version to use (defaults to 3
# if supported by client library)
ldap_version 3

# The distinguished name to bind to the server with.
# Optional: default is to bind anonymously.
#binddn cn=proxyuser,dc=padl,dc=com

# The credentials to bind with. 
# Optional: default is no credential.
#bindpw secret

# The distinguished name to bind to the server with
# if the effective user ID is root. Password is
# stored in /etc/ldap.secret (mode 600)
rootbinddn cn=Manager,dc=souad,dc=com

# The port.
# Optional: default is 389.
#port 389

# The search scope.
#scope sub
#scope one
#scope base

# Search timelimit
#timelimit 30

# Bind/connect timelimit
#bind_timelimit 30

# Reconnect policy: hard (default) will retry connecting to
# the software with exponential backoff, soft will fail
# immediately.
#bind_policy hard

# Idle timelimit; client will close connections
# (nss_ldap only) if the server has not been contacted
# for the number of seconds specified below.
#idle_timelimit 3600

# Filter to AND with uid=%s
#pam_filter objectclass=account

# The user ID attribute (defaults to uid)
#pam_login_attribute uid

# Search the root DSE for the password policy (works
# with Netscape Directory Server)
#pam_lookup_policy yes

# Check the 'host' attribute for access control
# Default is no; if set to yes, and user has no
# value for the host attribute, and pam_ldap is
# configured for account management (authorization)
# then the user will not be allowed to login.
#pam_check_host_attr yes

# Check the 'authorizedService' attribute for access
# control
# Default is no; if set to yes, and the user has no
# value for the authorizedService attribute, and
# pam_ldap is configured for account management
# (authorization) then the user will not be allowed
# to login.
#pam_check_service_attr yes

# Group to enforce membership of
#pam_groupdn cn=PAM,ou=Groups,dc=padl,dc=com

# Group member attribute
#pam_member_attribute uniquemember

# Specify a minium or maximum UID number allowed
#pam_min_uid 0
#pam_max_uid 0

# Template login attribute, default template user
# (can be overriden by value of former attribute
# in user's entry)
#pam_login_attribute userPrincipalName
#pam_template_login_attribute uid
#pam_template_login nobody

# HEADS UP: the pam_crypt, pam_nds_passwd,
# and pam_ad_passwd options are no
# longer supported.
#
# Do not hash the password at all; presume
# the directory server will do it, if
# necessary. This is the default.
pam_password md5

# Hash password locally; required for University of
# Michigan LDAP server, and works with Netscape
# Directory Server if you're using the UNIX-Crypt
# hash mechanism and not using the NT Synchronization
# service. 
#pam_password crypt

# Remove old password first, then update in
# cleartext. Necessary for use with Novell
# Directory Services (NDS)
#pam_password clear_remove_old
#pam_password nds

# RACF is an alias for the above. For use with
# IBM RACF
#pam_password racf

# Update Active Directory password, by
# creating Unicode password and updating
# unicodePwd attribute.
#pam_password ad

# Use the OpenLDAP password change
# extended operation to update the password.
#pam_password exop

# Redirect users to a URL or somesuch on password
# changes.
#pam_password_prohibit_message Please visit http://internal to change your password.

# RFC2307bis naming contexts
# Syntax:
# nss_base_XXX      base?scope?filter
# where scope is {base,one,sub}
# and filter is a filter to be &'d with the
# default filter.
# You can omit the suffix eg:
# nss_base_passwd   ou=People,
# to append the default base DN but this
# may incur a small performance impact.
#nss_base_passwd    ou=People,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_shadow    ou=People,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_group     ou=Group,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_hosts     ou=Hosts,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_services  ou=Services,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_networks  ou=Networks,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_protocols ou=Protocols,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_rpc       ou=Rpc,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_ethers    ou=Ethers,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_netmasks  ou=Networks,dc=padl,dc=com?ne
#nss_base_bootparams    ou=Ethers,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_aliases   ou=Aliases,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_netgroup  ou=Netgroup,dc=padl,dc=com?one

# attribute/objectclass mapping
# Syntax:
#nss_map_attribute  rfc2307attribute    mapped_attribute
#nss_map_objectclass    rfc2307objectclass  mapped_objectclass

# configure --enable-nds is no longer supported.
# NDS mappings
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member

# Services for UNIX 3.5 mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount User
#nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount User
#nss_map_attribute uid msSFU30Name
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember msSFU30PosixMember
#nss_map_attribute userPassword msSFU30Password
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory msSFU30HomeDirectory
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory msSFUHomeDirectory
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup Group
#pam_login_attribute msSFU30Name
#pam_filter objectclass=User
#pam_password ad

# configure --enable-mssfu-schema is no longer supported.
# Services for UNIX 2.0 mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount User
#nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount user
#nss_map_attribute uid msSFUName
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember posixMember
#nss_map_attribute userPassword msSFUPassword
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory msSFUHomeDirectory
#nss_map_attribute shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup Group
#nss_map_attribute cn msSFUName
#pam_login_attribute msSFUName
#pam_filter objectclass=User
#pam_password ad

# RFC 2307 (AD) mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount user
#nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount user
#nss_map_attribute uid sAMAccountName
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory unixHomeDirectory
#nss_map_attribute shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup group
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
#pam_login_attribute sAMAccountName
#pam_filter objectclass=User
#pam_password ad

# configure --enable-authpassword is no longer supported
# AuthPassword mappings
#nss_map_attribute userPassword authPassword

# AIX SecureWay mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount aixAccount
#nss_base_passwd ou=aixaccount,?one
#nss_map_attribute uid userName
#nss_map_attribute gidNumber gid
#nss_map_attribute uidNumber uid
#nss_map_attribute userPassword passwordChar
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup aixAccessGroup
#nss_base_group ou=aixgroup,?one
#nss_map_attribute cn groupName
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
#pam_login_attribute userName
#pam_filter objectclass=aixAccount
#pam_password clear

# Netscape SDK LDAPS
#ssl on

# Netscape SDK SSL options
#sslpath /etc/ssl/certs

# OpenLDAP SSL mechanism
# start_tls mechanism uses the normal LDAP port, LDAPS typically 636
#ssl start_tls
#ssl on

# OpenLDAP SSL options
# Require and verify server certificate (yes/no)
# Default is to use libldap's default behavior, which can be configured in
# /etc/openldap/ldap.conf using the TLS_REQCERT setting.  The default for
# OpenLDAP 2.0 and earlier is "no", for 2.1 and later is "yes".
#tls_checkpeer yes

# CA certificates for server certificate verification
# At least one of these are required if tls_checkpeer is "yes"
#tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/ca.cert
#tls_cacertdir /etc/ssl/certs

# Seed the PRNG if /dev/urandom is not provided
#tls_randfile /var/run/egd-pool

# SSL cipher suite
# See man ciphers for syntax
#tls_ciphers TLSv1

# Client certificate and key
# Use these, if your server requires client authentication.
#tls_cert
#tls_key

# Disable SASL security layers. This is needed for AD.
#sasl_secprops maxssf=0

# Override the default Kerberos ticket cache location.
#krb5_ccname FILE:/etc/.ldapcache

# SASL mechanism for PAM authentication - use is experimental
# at present and does not support password policy control
#pam_sasl_mech DIGEST-MD5
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers avahi,avahi-autoipd,backup,bin,colord,daemon,dnsmasq,games,gnats,hplip,irc,kernoops,libuuid,lightdm,list,lp,mail,man,messagebus,news,proxy,pulse,root,rtkit,saned,speech-dispatcher,sync,sys,syslog,usbmux,uucp,whoopsie,www-data
```

The file `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=souad,dc=com
URI ldap://192.168.95.133:389

#SIZELIMIT  12
#TIMELIMIT  15
#DEREF      never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hi Souad. Can you post you pam-ldap.conf as well as your libnss-ldap.conf.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I needed to **allow** the listing of LDAP users!

Edit `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`, and change `enumerate = false` to `enumerate = true`.

Answer (score 3):

I often see this kind of thing when I have a problem with the the connection to LDAP. Make sure you have the correct URL for your server. Personally, I avoid the ldapi:// URL. It has only caused problems in the past. Make sure that the binddn can bind. Check both secret files, if you are using password authentication and bind manually from the box to ldap.

Hope this was helpful.

**Revision**

```
#binddn cn=proxyuser,dc=padl,dc=com
#bindpw secret
```

Your binddn and it's secret are not being used. Ordinarily I use both to ensure that the configuration is working.

**Revision 2**

Sorry I couldn't be of more help. But I would expect two conf files

1. /etc/libnss-ldapp.conf
2. /etc/pam_ldap.conf

Both these files plus /etc/nsswitch.conf are used to configure LDAP authentication. Your nsswitch.conf is fine. The effect you are describing comes usually when the user can't be authenticated against LDAP. There's probably a short pause before getent quits. The error messages are found in /var/log/auth.log. Often the problem is that the binddn can't bind with LDAP and authentication will only take place after this bind is successful.

Like I say, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: The bind is working as well. This command gives the right information : `ldapsearch -x -h 192.168.95.133 -p 389 -LLL -b "dc=souad,dc=com" uid=fzhang`. My URL looks like : `ldap//192.168.95.133:389/`

Comment: Have a look at your ldap log file see what ldap is logging when you bind. With bind I mean getent passwd.

Comment: One other thing. Remove or mask the BASE & URI directives in ldap.conf.

Comment: In which file should I use the binddn and the bindpw ?

Comment: In both. libnss-ldap.conf & pam-ldap.conf

Comment: I cann't find the file `pam-ldap.conf`

Comment: Well I used the bindpw and the binddn but no effect...